# Cannot access http://localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, localhost

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails, I have followed the instructions from this [page](http://www.buildingwebapps.com/articles/6491-setting-up-rails-on-windows-vista) to get rails installed on my PC.

I am also trying to follow this [webcast](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts) to try and learn the language and framework. Everything is working so far, apart from the fact that I cannot access

```
http://localhost:3000
http://0.0.0.0:3000
http://127.0.0.1:3000, or
http://<actual IP address>:3000
```

locally. If I try the from another PC on my network then it works great. I have tried in Chrome, Firefox and IE7 but none work.

Has anyone else had this problem?

EDIT: Typical!! It's started working now. I have no idea why, I am typing the exact same address in to the address bar and it now works. But only if I use `http://127.0.0.1:3000`, localhost doesn't work. I do run IIS ASP.NET/ASP websites on this machine, and they work fine with localhost.

EDIT 2: If I trying pinging localhost it actually says

```
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

0.0.0.0 yields...

```
PING: transmit failed, error code 1214
```

only 127.0.0.1 seems to work. I did have IPv6 turned on, so I've disabled that and will try again tomorrow to see if a reboot helps.

Comment: Sounds like a borked network setup to me. Are you using a proxy? (added as comment since it doesn't really answer anything).

Comment: Are you running any kind of 3rd party firewall? I had a similar issue arise with AVG Internet Security and Apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you telnet to the port?  Try:

```
telnet localhost 3000
```

That should tell you if the ports unavailable at the TCP level, or whether something's going on at the HTTP level.

Ping might not work if ICMP is disabled, which could be completely unrelated to your issue.

Also, try looking in your hosts file for any redirections:

```
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Comment: I checked my hosts file and had 2 entries in there for localhost, one for 127.0.0.1 and another for ::1. I commented out the latter and now IE and firefox work with localhost:3000. Many thanks.

Comment: Connection refused.  http://rubyonrails.org/download, just above `editors`, one line up.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue as well with Vagrant. The secret is to run

```
bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

What 0.0.0.0 means is to listen to all interfaces, not just on localhost. The alternative is to SSH into the vagrant machine with a SOCKS proxy.

```
ssh -C -D 8080 vagrant@localhost
```

Open up your Internet explorer proxy settings and set the SOCKS v5 proxy to port 8080.

Answer (score 6):

In order to access `http://localhost:3000` you need to run the local Rails server in a terminal window:

```
$ rails server
```

This is described in [this section of the Rails Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec%3arails_server).

*Note*: I am the presenter of the screencasts in question.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to do the simple

```
    rails s
```

Another (more specifically) is

```
    rails start localhost 0.0.0.0
```

or

```
    rails start 0.0.0.0
```

another way is

```
    rails s 0.0.0.0
```

all of these works

Answer (score 1):

I had an epic issue with my System Path (Environmental Variable) not being set properly.

Simple copy paste job, unplugged the 1 week stalled Ruby installation.

`Control Panel > System > Advanced tab > Environment Variables > System variables > Path... Edit...`

Make sure it contains these paths (among others)...

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`

Answer (score 1):

I had your same identical problem. You have simply to run

```
$ rails server
```

from inside the folder of your application, not outside...so, if you have your application in

*C:\Sites\myapp\blog*

and blog is the folder where live your app, the command has to be prompted from here. Launching it from myapp folder won't work.

Comment: running "command inside the folder of your application, not outside" solved my issue also.. Should marked as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly using a proxy but haven't listed localhost as proxy exception?

Comment: i'm not using a proxy for the local network, or any other network for that matter.

Comment: @bluebrother this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling your firewall?  They can cause pesky problems at times.

Comment: @Jason Baker, this should be a comment